# Final class method not getting tested as desired with Mockito 2

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, android-testing

As described in [Mockito 2 docs](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods) we can now Mock final classes, so I tried to do it in a simple project, but the results are not proper.
Here is my project structure
[image: as described in link]

Here is the org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker text file

```
mock-maker-inline
```

Here is a demo activity for testing

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }

    private fun onLoginPressed(email:String, password:String){

    }

     fun isEmailValid(email: String):Boolean{
        return true
    }
}
```

here is the test class

```
class LoginActivityTest{

    @Test
    fun checkLoginValidity(){
        val lognActivity = Mockito.mock(LoginActivity::class.java)
        assert(lognActivity.isEmailValid("yuo"))
    }
}
```

The test should have passed, since I am always returning true, but here is what I get.

[image]

I have also marked and unmarked the resources directory as test resources root, but nothing really happened.

Can you point me out, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mocked your `Activity` class, so all it's methods allways returns "default" value (for `boolean` it is `false`). You need to say `Mockito` to call real method of class.

```
`when`(lognActivity.isEmailValid(ArgumentMatchers.any() ?: ""))
    .thenCallRealMethod()
```

By the way, it is better to use that solution for abstract classes only, because you can't create instance of it with another way. If your class is not abstract, just create it (for `Activity` test better to use [specific tools](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing)).

Answer (score 1):

Mocking final (Kotlin) classes with Mockito works fine and your setup is obviously correct (you'd get an error if mocking that `Activity` had failed). There's something wrong with the way you're trying to test.

Mockito is used to mock *the dependencies* of the class you want to test, not the class you want to test itself.

What you're doing there is mocking your `LoginActivity`, then asserting that it returns some value. For methods that return a `boolean` like `isEmailValid(...)`, a mock per default returns `false`. 
You don't test mocks, there's no point in that. You want to test a 'real' instance of the class under test.

If you wanted to test that `Activity`, you'd just create one with `val classToTest = LoginActivity()`, then do your `assert`.

This might (not sure) work for this very simple case, but in general you don't unit-test `Activity`s, because there's too much Android-specific stuff going on, like inflating the layout (`setContentView`) which doesn't work in a unit test.

That's why concepts like MVP or MVVM gained popularity, to move as much logic away from Android-classes like `Activity` and then make it testable.

For your case, to get you started, you could write an `EmailChecker` class that you a. then use in your Activity to check the email `String` and b. can better test with a unit test.